# Validate input field only after clicking save button on angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, validation

I want to validate my input required fields and only show an error message, after clicking the save button(submit) in my form. 
What is the best way to do it in angularjs ?

Thanks,

Comment: what you have tried\

Comment: see this:http://blog.yodersolutions.com/bootstrap-form-validation-done-right-in-angularjs/

Answer (score 0):

please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25278251/angularjs-form-validation-directive-for-showing-input-errors/25279903#25279903)

example  explained you can find in that link

```
module = angular.module('app', []);

module.directive('showErrors', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: '^form',
      link: function (scope, el, attrs, formCtrl) {
        // find the text box element, which has the 'name' attribute
        var inputEl   = el[0].querySelector("[name]");
        // convert the native text box element to an angular element
        var inputNgEl = angular.element(inputEl);
        // get the name on the text box
        var inputName = inputNgEl.attr('name');

        // only apply the has-error class after the user leaves the text box
        inputNgEl.bind('blur', function() {
          el.toggleClass('has-error', formCtrl[inputName].$invalid);
        })
      }
    }
  });

module.controller('NewUserController', function($scope) {
  $scope.save = function() {
    if ($scope.userForm.$valid) {
      alert('User saved');
      $scope.reset();
    } else {
      alert("There are invalid fields");
    }
  };

  $scope.reset = function() {
    $scope.user = { name: '', email: '' };
  }
});
```